# loop over items in an array and spread them in one line in php

Tags: php, arrays

i know its kinda stupid but what am after is,

```
// an array of some unknown items from the database
$array = ['item1','item2','item3'];

// i think it should be done with For loop but not sure how, so anyhow
// the loop should repeat (name contains '$item' and) for each item of the $array and put them in a query like below
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $query = [
        'q' => "name contains '$item1' and name contains '$item2' and name contains '$etc...'"
    ];
}
```

currently what am doing is making the query one by one which is causing overhead and with big array it takes too long, so i thought of combining the whole thing in one query which should reduce the time drastically.

Comment: Are you looking for `implode()`?

Comment: Is the content you want to add always static? If so you might be able to use `concat` in the query and get the data back as you want.

Comment: @Rizier123 i think implode could do the trick, can u plz add an answer with some code to make it easier to visualize the whole scenario ?

Comment: @chris85 nop they are not static, they are dynamic according to what i get from the db.

Comment: Yea, so if db values you can use `concat` and put the column names in there.

Comment: can u add an answer with some code ?

Comment: I don't know what your querying so hard to say. Link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat. Sample `concat('static', column1, ' more content', column2)`

Comment: @ctf0 See the manual or https://3v4l.org/HRS35 as a simple example how the function works what it does and maybe it is what you want, since I can't really tell what exactly you are trying to do here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// an array of some unknown items from the database
$array = ['item1','item2','item3'];
$q = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $q[]  = "name contains '$item'";
}

$query['q'] = implode(' and ', $q);
```

Answer (score 1):

Somethig like this should do the trick :

```
$array = ['item1','item2','item3'];

// init $query as array
$query = [];
// init $query 'q' index as empty string
$query['q'] = '';

// then loop the array of items, and concat what you need    
foreach ($array as $item)
{
    $query['q'] .= " name contains '$item' and";
}

// remove whitespaces from start and end of the string
$query['q'] = trim($query['q']);
// remove the ' and' from the end of the string (0 = start of string, -4 = 4 before the end of the string)
$query['q'] = substr($query['q'], 0, -4);
```

This will return : `name contains 'item1' and name contains 'item2' and name contains 'item3'`

Becare, it's a simple exemple, you should test for exemple with `empty($array)` that the array contains at least one item, of the substr will return false (or null, im not sure about this)

Answer (score 0):

no `foreach` needed:

```
$query['q'] = "name contains " . implode(" and name contains ", $array);
```

but you will want to ensure the array has something in it.. :-)

Comment: ...go ahead and edit your answer to include a simple if statement.  Otherwise this is the answer I would have posted.